# Changing vim selected text colors

Tags: vim, background-color, color-scheme, selectedtext

I would like to add a color scheme rule in vim in which I could apply black over white in a text everytime it's selected in visual mode.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
hi Visual gui=NONE guibg=White guifg=Black
```

If that's what you were aiming for, add it to your colorscheme or your _vimrc file.

Comment: I'm using vim, not gvim, doesn't that only apply to gvim ? It didn't work.

Comment: doing `cterm` prefix instead of `gui` worked for linux terminal, but in `putty` (ssh client for windows) when I select text it's white over black, not the opposite....

Comment: @Niloct - Yeah, sorry about that. A lot of people round here mean gvim when they say vim. // 2nd comment: Also check your VisualNOS highlighting.